# Duplicate title error in Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

I have changed some URLs in my site then to prevent Webmaster Tools duplicate error I redirected (301) old URLs to new URLs also I tried to remove old URLs in "Optimization > Remove URLs" section of Webmaster Tools and still I get "Duplicate title error".

I want to know is any problem in redirecting?

For example, `http://www.example.com/index.php` is redirected to `http://www.example.com/index`.

P.S.: I used Fiddler to check 301 redirect and think it should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Applying 301 redirects is the best practice in your case.

You need to wait a little bit because Google needs time to take into account your 301 redirects. When it will be taken into account, duplicate title errors in your Webmaster Tools account will disappear.